# My array displays only 300 elements in C++ Visual studio

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2012, console, output

I have written a code wherein I have an int array of 1000 capacity.
I have randomized each element of the array. When I try to print out all 1000 of the elements. It only displays 300 lines/outputs in the console window. I wrote this in C++ and using Visual Studio 2013

My code (Don't worry I have all the necesary header files):

```
int main(void)

{

srand(time(NULL));

    int large[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {

        large[i] = rand() % 10000000000;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        cout << large[i] << endl;
    }


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Explain flushing pleas
?

Comment: Flushing makes sure everything written to the stream gets output to the console. For example `std::endl` flushes the stream. As you seem to have used that, it's not the problem.

Comment: The default screen buffer height on the Visual Studio console window is 300 lines.

Comment: Drew, can I increase it?

Comment: As a side note, `rand() % 10000000000` doesn't make any sense because `rand()` returns an `int` and the maximum value of an `int` is `2147483647` but `10000000000` is greater than that.

Comment: Which idiot upvoted this? In which way this question makes up a MCVE?

Comment: Oh hey, that's another question I wanted to ask. Basically my array has to be 1000 elements and can be ANY number. is writing just "rand()" giving me an unlimited range. i.e. any number from 0 to 2147483647?

Comment: `rand()` gives you an `int` i.e. `unsigned int` i.e. any number from `-2147483647` or `-2147483648` to `+2147483647`.

Comment: @zenith Thank you. I'll use  rand() % 2147483647

Comment: @Ansh [Works here](http://ideone.com/QSqJRc)

Comment: @Ansh _"Oh hey, that's another question I wanted to ask."_ Another question is _another question_! Behave along the rules here please.

Comment: @Ansh Sorry I made a mistake. `rand()` actually returns a number between `0` and `RAND_MAX`. And `RAND_MAX` is probably `2147483647 ` on your system. Btw `rand() % n` will give you anything from `0` to `n-1`, not `0` to `n`.

Comment: @zenith I just found out that rand_max is 32767. Thought you'd like to know perhaps.

Comment: @Ansh Yes that's [entirely possible](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/). But that means you're not able to get values greater than `32767` from `rand()` unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default screen buffer height on the Visual Studio 2013 console window is 300 lines.

Right click on the window title bar and go to "Properties",  "Layout" and under "Screen Buffer Size" change "Height" to 1000.